# 100% height between navbar and sticky Bootstrap footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height, footer, navbar

In this project http://fiddle.jshell.net/e43duahb/

I want the div with the class apresentacao to be window height less 100px of the footer.

I've tried jQuery `<script>$(".apresentacao").css('min-height', $(window).height()-'100px');</script>` and it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$(window).height()-'100px'` with this `$(window).height()-100 + 'px'`

Here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uhf4ss03/

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS function called calc that is starting to get pretty good support. The syntax works as followed:

```
height: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

or

```
height: calc(100% - 100px);
```

(Note that the whitespace around the operators is significant)

This allows true dynamic computational support in CSS. With a preprocessor, you can only combine static lengths with static lengths, and relative lengths with relative ones.

Calc is supported since Chrome 19, Firefox 4, and IE9. The feature isn't quite widely supported enough to use it widely, but it will be not too far into the future and it's something to remember and look forward to.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it would work perfectly but I've decided to use the jQuery solution. I'll keep your solution in my mind for future projects.